# How can I prevent shapes from changing on mouseclick?

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, mouseclick-event

I am having a problem with my code, if I click on rectangle and do the mouse clicks on the screen it will show the shape and it works fine.. but if I clicked on the circle after that, all the rec
tangles that have been stored stays on same location but changes to circle. how can I prevent the shapes that have been stored from changing?

First Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MouseClick implements ActionListener{
    private static int x,y;
    private static DrawingObjects object = new DrawingObjects();
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("MouseClick");


   MouseClick(){
       dObjects();
   }
   void dObjects() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        frame.add(object);
        frame.add(panel);
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setSize(10, 300);
        panel.setLocation(100, 200);
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        object.addMouseListener(new AL());

        Button rect = new Button("Rectangle");
        Button oval = new Button("Circle");
        panel.add(rect);
        panel.add(oval);
        rect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {           
                object.setType(1);
}
        });         

   oval.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {            
        object.setType(2);
}
   });         }

   public static void main(String[] args){

      new MouseClick();
    }
    static class AL extends MouseAdapter{
        public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e){
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();
            object.drawing(x, y);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Second Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.*;
public class DrawingObjects extends JPanel{
    private ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();
    public int shapetype ;

    public void drawing(int x, int y){
        points.add(new Point(x, y));
        repaint();
    }


    public void setType(int choice){
        if(choice==1){
            shapetype = 1;
        }

        else if (choice ==2){
            shapetype = 2;
        }

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);


        if(shapetype == 1){

        for(Point p : points){
            g.fillRect(p.x, p.y, 60, 20);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            repaint();
        }
        }

        else if (shapetype == 2){
            for(Point p : points){
                g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 20, 20);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                repaint();

            }

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `state` should only be used to create the shape, not paint it.  You will need to generate some kind of "shape" data, which knows how it should be painted, or use the `Shape` API in `Graphics2D`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Could you explain more please, I didn't quite understand what are you referring to with state.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because the `shapetype` is not stored along with the points on which the shapes are drawn. As a result, within the `paintComponent` method, when all shapes in locations stored in `points` array get redrawn, they use the current value of `shapetype`. Not the value of `shapetype` when the shape was created for the first time.

A simple (yet not the best) solution, with minimum code change would be to store the `shapetype` as follows.

In `DrawingObjects` class, add another array to store the `shapetype`.

`private ArrayList<Integer> shapeTypes = new ArrayList<>();`

Update the `drawing` method as follows to store the current shapetype along with the point.

```
public void drawing(int x, int y) {
    points.add(new Point(x, y));
    shapeTypes.add(shapetype);
    repaint();
}
```

Refer the stored `shapetype` when repainting the shapes as follows.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        Point p = points.get(i);
        if (shapeTypes.get(i) == 1) {

          g.fillRect(p.x, p.y, 60, 20);
          g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
          repaint();    
        } else if (shapeTypes.get(i) == 2) {
          g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 20, 20);
          g.setColor(Color.RED);
          repaint();    
        }
    }
}
```

A better design would be to create a separate class with the capability to store the location as well as the shape type with the implementation on how it should be painted.